# How to show that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(n-1)\Phi(x)^{n-2}\phi(x)^2dx$? decreases in $n$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, normal-distribution

I was working on a research project that involves taking the integral of

$$(n-1)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Phi\left(x\right)^{n-2}\phi\left(x\right)^2dx,$$ where $\Phi(.)$ is the CDF for standard normal, $\phi$ the PDF, $\alpha>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n>3$.

Eventually, I wish to show that the whole expression decreases monotonically as $n$ increases.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you already know that the sequence is monotonically decreasing, or would you like to check whether it is true or not?

Comment: @Avitus I think it is decreasing. I just wanted to be able to formally prove it. I actually think it generalizes to other types of distributions as well.

Comment: I quickly did $f_{n+1}-f_n$ arriving at the integral $f_{n+1}-f_n=n\int \phi^2(x) \Phi^{n-1}(x)(1+(\frac{1}{n}-1)\Phi^{-1}(x))dx$; the function in the brackets is  negative for $x\in[-\infty, a_n]$ where $a_n$ is s.t. $\Phi(a_n)=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Could you please check if it is ok?

Comment: when $x=\Phi^{-1}(1-\frac{1}{n})$ I got the part inside the bracket equals $1+(1/n-1)\times (1-1/n)=\frac{1}{n^2}>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integration by parts using $u=\varphi$ and $v'=(n-1)\varphi\Phi^{n-2}$, hence $u'(x)=-x\varphi(x)$ and $v=\Phi^{n-1}$, shows that the $n$th term is $$A_n=\int_\mathbb Rx\varphi(x)\Phi(x)^{n-1}\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty x\varphi(x)B_n(\Phi(x))\mathrm dx,$$ where $$B_n(t)=t^{n-1}-(1-t)^{n-1}.$$
For every $t$ in $(\frac12,1)$ and every $n\geqslant3$, $$B_n(t)-B_{n-1}(t)=t(1-t)((1-t)^{n-3}-t^{n-3})\leqslant0,$$ hence $A_n\leqslant A_{n-1}$, that is, the sequence $(A_n)_{n\geqslant2}$ is non increasing.